# How to get a name of function that click the button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vba, button

I know almost nothing about JavaScript. 
But I am writing a macro in VBA and I need to go to the given website and click the button. Unfortunately without any knowledge about JavaScript it is not so easy for me.

The HTML code of the button is the following:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small" id="button-1180" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" style="margin: 0px; padding: 1px; border-radius: 0px; left: 378px; top: 0px; width: 24px; height: 24px; right: auto; font-size: 20px !important; background-color: rgb(7, 95, 157);"
  hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" data-componentid="button-1180" data-qtip="Login">
  <span class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-small " id="button-1180-btnWrap" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-ref="btnWrap" unselectable="on">
    <span class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-small  x-btn-no-text x-btn-icon x-btn-icon-left x-btn-button-center " id="button-1180-btnEl" role="presentation" style="height: auto;" data-ref="btnEl" unselectable="on">
      <span class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-small x-fa fa-chevron-right white-glyph " id="button-1180-btnIconEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnIconEl" unselectable="on" qa="btnIcon-loginButton"></span>
      <span class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small" id="button-1180-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Unfortunately there is no onclick attribute in this html code which is fired when I click the button. I suppose that there is a function written in JavaScript that is responsible for clicking a button. If for example this function will be called Run(), then I just need to set onclick attribute to be equal to Run() in my VBA code and then I can use a click property in VBA.

My question is: If I click Inspect element on a website I see an HTML code and other overlaps ,e.g. DOM Explorer, Console, Debugger, Network, UI Responsiveness, Profiler, Memory and Emulation. How can I see which function is calling when I click the button. I am working in Internet Explorer and I can not change it.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: That is not even funny. How can you expect anyone to read through that.

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: What tool or framework generates this kind of code for a simple button?

Comment: I just copied this code from 'DOM Explorer' overlap, so I do not know why somebody created it in this way. Unfortunately it handicaps to control this button, e.g. by clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onClick()`, but then your button has to 'listen' to a click event to happen. You should probably look for javascript similar to this:

```
document.getElementById("button-1180").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: When I run this command in a Console I obtained: 'Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference'. What I should write inplace of myFunction?

Comment: Your question was how to find the function that is called by clicking the button when there is no `onClick`. My answer is, that you should look for code similar to my example. So look for 'addEvenListener' in your javascript that is connected to your button, or perhaps even better: do a search for `button-1180`